# Existe alguma maneira de obter o valor original de um atributo de um Model depois modificá-lo?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou usando o Laravel 5 e gostaria de saber se, depois de modificar um atributo de um model, é possível recuperá-lo.

Por exemplo:

```
 $usuario = Usuario::where(['nome' => 'Wallace'])->first();

 $usuario->nome = 'Guilherme';
```

No exemplo acima, eu modifiquei o atributo `nome` do model. Queria saber se tem como recuperar o atributo `nome`. O Laravel "salva" o valor original em algum lugar antes de salvar as alterações?

É claro que eu conseguiria fazer isso fazendo outra consulta, mas não creio que esse seja o melhor caminho. Então não aceitarei respostas do tipo.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum jeito de recuperar o valor inicial do atributo "nome" do model acima, sem fazer outra consulta.

Comment: porque não faz na linha a seguir de `$usuario = Usuario::wher...` isto: `$nomeOrig = $usuario->nome`. E depois fica com o nome original retornado guardado. Isto é se percebi bem a pergunta

Comment: Também dá @Miguel, mas se fosse vários campos eu teria que fazer um por um, certo? Na verdade eu sei a resposta, só queria mesmo instigar a ter mais conteúdo de [tag:Laravel] no site e ver a criatividade do pessoal :D

Comment: Aguardo a sua resposta então... Também estou curioso. Ou seja depois de fazer $usuario->save(); recuperar os dados que estavam lá antes?

Comment: @Miguel não, eu falei "antes". "Depois" eu já sei que não tem como, pois os dados já são da tabela :D

Comment: Pois, claro, mas podia ser que ficasse na sessão implicitamente sem sabermos

Comment: Ok curioso na mesma. Já percebi o que quer dizer. Mas não sei

Comment: @Miguel na verdade tem o **getOriginal** :D. Já falei demais

Comment: Acabei de ver sim. Mas isso não esconde a pass/token. testei aqui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Laravel salva os atributos originais do modelo dentro da propriedade `original`.

```
$user = User::first();

$user->name = 'Rafael';

dd(
    $user->getAttributes(), // contém o atributo nome novo.
    $user->getOriginal() // contém o atributo nome antigo.
);
```

Se você desejar acessar um atributo específico dos valores originais, basta passar o nome dele por parâmetro de `Model::getOriginal`.

Exemplo:

```
  $user->getOriginal('name');
```

Você pode verificar direto na api, neste [link](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getOriginal).

Comment: Se me permite, adicionei alguns detalhes :p